# Querying Many-to-Many relationship gives error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tablePath')" in typeorm

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, typeorm

```js
@Entity()
export class Adlib {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false, length: 100 })
  prompt: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false, length: 200 })
  title: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  body: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Category)
  @JoinTable()
  categories: Category[];
}

@Entity()
export class Category {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false, unique: true, length: 50 })
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Adlib, (adlib) => adlib.categories)
  adlibs: Adlib[];

@CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

I currently can query the Adlib entity with the categories. But whenever I query the Category table with adlibs, it throws the  error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tablePath')."

I've switched the relation around where the join column is on the category entity and it does the opposite. Is there a better way to manage this many-to-many relationship than manually writing the junction table?

Here is the service that it is erroring at. The pagination class is essentially a wrapper that handles formatting the data.

```js
@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Category)
    private readonly categoryRepository: Repository<Category>,
  ) {}

  findAllPageable(
    categoryPaginationDto: CategoryPaginationDto,
  ): Promise<PaginationResponse<Category>> {
    return Pagination.paginate<Category>(
      this.categoryRepository,
      categoryPaginationDto,
      {
        where: {
          createdAt: LessThan(categoryPaginationDto.timestamp),
        },
        order: {
          createdAt: 'DESC',
        },
        relations: ['adlibs'],
      },
    );
  }
}
```